# Keybinding alt+up won't work in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, key-bindings

I want to copy the *Move Line Up/Down* keyboard shortcut of VS Code to Sublime Text 3 which uses `Ctrl`+`Up`/`Ctrl`+`Down` key bindings, so I placed the following in the User-defined key-bindings file:

```json
[
    {
        "keys": ["alt+up"], "command": "swap_line_up",
        "keys": ["alt+down"], "command": "swap_line_down"
    }
]
```

The `swap_line_down` works but the `swap_line_up` doesn't. I've already checked for conflicts within `Default(Windows).sublime-keymap`. I've tried to swap the commands to check if the problem is specific with `alt`+`up`

```json
[
    {
        "keys": ["alt+up"], "command": "swap_line_down",
        "keys": ["alt+down"], "command": "swap_line_up"
    }
]
```

and, indeed, now `swap_line_up` works but `swap_line_down` doesn't. So it seems `alt`+`up` is the problem. What seems to be the issue here?

Comment: What do you see if you open the Sublime console with `View > Show Console`, enter `sublime.log_input(True)` and then press that key sequence? If the answer is "nothing", then some external program is eating the key before Sublime can see it.

Comment: @OdatNurd It returns `key evt: alt+up`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your key bindings aren't specified correctly; each binding object should have a single `keys` and `command` (and optionally a single `args` and `context` key s well), but you have both specified in a single binding.

It should look more like this:

```json
[
    {
        "keys": ["alt+up"], "command": "swap_line_up",
    },
    {
        "keys": ["alt+down"], "command": "swap_line_down"
    },
]
```